# How to substitute variable in this Zsh expression?

Tags: shell, zsh

I need to substitute variable `x` in this expression:

```sh
my-func() {
  x="Hello world"
  y=${1:?Missing argument, use $x}
  echo -- $y
}
```

It prints `$x` on missing of the 1st function's argument instead of "Hello world". How to substitute variables in this error message? Is it possible at all?

Comment: I can't repro, `echo "${7:?Missing argument, use $HOME}"` interpolates my home directory like I would expect. I'm not entirely sure I understand if that's what you are asking, though.

Comment: I added function, it happens in the function. I run it under zsh: `. myfile.sh`, then `my-func`

Comment: Then why on Earth did you tag this [tag:bash]??

Comment: Ooh, sorry, it is ZSHism, I was sure that zsh behavior is identical to bash. It's surprise for me.

Comment: @Paul-AG : I don't understand what you mean by _substitute variables in this error message_- The error message, which is printed if someone forgets to pass a parameter to the function, is _Missing argument, use Hello world_. In this message, the variable `x` **is** obviously substituted. of course the wording of the error message si silly, but this is up to you. So what else do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With 'zsh', the word in '${var:?work) is not interpolated, and is printed as-is. Most likely a bug, as bash, dash, ksh and other will follow the POSIX standard: From https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02

> ${parameter:?[word]} Indicate Error if Null or Unset. If parameter is
> unset or null, the expansion of word (or a message indicating it is
> unset if word is omitted) shall be written to standard error and the
> shell exits with a non-zero exit status. Otherwise, the value of
> parameter shall be substituted. An interactive shell need not exit.

The alternative solution is to put an explicit check:

```
my-func() {
  x="Hello world"
#  y=${1:?Missing argument, use $x}
  if [ ! "$1 ] ; then
      echo "$funcstack[1]: $LINENO: \$1: missing argument use $x" >&2
      exit 1
  fi
  y=${1}
  echo -- $y
}
```

More fancier code can be written by replacing the 'exit' with 'throw' (will need autoload).